# AWS Steps Function: timed out Fargate task not automatically killed

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

I have a [AWS Step Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/getting-started.html) which is configured to run a [Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html) task, wait for completion and do some other work. The Fargate task is a long running process which can potentially get stuck during execution. To avoid this, I have configured a [TimeoutSeconds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html) parameter in the task definition:

```yaml
StartAt: FargateWorker
States:
  FargateWorker:
    Type: Task
    Resource: arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.waitForTaskToken
    InputPath: $
    ResultPath: $.workerResult
    OutputPath: $
    TimeoutSeconds: 3
    Parameters:
      Cluster: "#{EcsCluster}"
      TaskDefinition: "#{EcsTaskDefinition}"
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      EnableExecuteCommand: true
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          Subnets:
            - xxx
            - yyy
            - zzz
          AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
      Overrides:
        ContainerOverrides:
          - Name: container-${env:STACK_NAME}
            Environment:
              - Name: TASK_TOKEN
                "Value.$": $$.Task.Token
    Catch:
      - ErrorEquals: ["States.ALL"]
        Next: CatchAllFallback
    Next: Done
```

I can see the state machine correctly moves to the `CatchAllFallback` state after `TimeoutSeconds` are passed, but the problem is that the Fargate container is still running, the state machine doesn't kill it. I need the container to be killed when the timeout triggers, so I don't end having a lot of zombie containers running until manual intervention. Is this something that can be addressed automatically by AWS in some way? Or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle it would be specifically catch the timeout and run a step to kill the Fargate Task like so?

```js
// Kill Task Lambda. Reference from [AWS Docs][1]
var params = {
  task: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  cluster: 'STRING_VALUE',
  reason: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
ecs.stopTask(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

```yaml
# State Machine
StartAt: FargateWorker
States:
  FargateWorker:
    Type: Task
    Resource: arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.waitForTaskToken
    InputPath: $
    ResultPath: $.workerResult
    OutputPath: $
    TimeoutSeconds: 3
    Parameters:
      Cluster: "#{EcsCluster}"
      TaskDefinition: "#{EcsTaskDefinition}"
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      EnableExecuteCommand: true
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          Subnets:
            - xxx
            - yyy
            - zzz
          AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
      Overrides:
        ContainerOverrides:
          - Name: container-${env:STACK_NAME}
            Environment:
              - Name: TASK_TOKEN
                "Value.$": $$.Task.Token
    Catch:
      - ErrorEquals: ["States.Timeout"]
        Next: StopTimedOutTask
    Next: Done

  StopTimedOutTask:
    Type: Task
    Resource:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - initializer
        - Arn
    ResultPath: $.filesInfo
    Next: ArchiveTransformAndSave
```

Comment: I was thinking about something like this, but is it possible to pass the specific task Arn to the `StopTimedOutTask`? I can have potentially many running tasks from different services, I need to know which one specifically needs to be killed